# Where to find WIFI Direct technical materials?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi-direct

I'd like to get more familiar with WIFI Direct's Protocol and OTA Flow. I searched google, but cannot seem to find any materials which discuss the protocol in detail. At least not for free. Does anyone know where can I find such articles?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can get them from here [WiFi Alliance specs](https://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/published-specifications), but it will cost you about 300 dollars.

Comment: I know WIFI Alliance, the spec is not free. Actually, i did not need the full spec. i only need some documents which explain the WIFI more detaily from technical aspect, include the discovery, connect, negotiate, ip address assigement, gourp create/remove.....procedure flow.  any one can share it?

Answer (score 1):

@nicefuture: you want low level technical details on how the mechanics of wifi direct work? well that sounds exactly like the kind of information their p2p spec will contain. you likely won't need the other spec, so it should just be US$199

But that aside - have you been through the free white papers on the wifi alliance's wifi direct page? here's some good ones it points to:

https://www.wi-fi.org/register.php?file=wp_Wi-Fi_Direct_20101022_Consumer.pdf

http://www.wi-fi.org/register.php?file=wp_Wi-Fi_Direct_20101025_Industry.pdf

the industry white paper gives a good overview of the mechanisms and capabilities that wifi direct contains, and these were enough to get me a product development project started up at my work with authorisation to order a couple of wifi direct phones and some new wifi direct embedded evaluation boards so I can explore the technology further.